# Where can I eat dishes that feature in western countries' Chinese restaurants?

Tags: food-and-drink, where-on-earth, asia, local-cuisine

... apart from western countries like the Australia or the USA themselves.

During my visit to Taiwan, I wasn't able to find the dishes I'd typically encounter in a Chinese restaurant in Australia or the United States, such as sweet and sour pork, honey chicken, Mongolian lamb/beef, and fried ice cream.

I have two main theories on why this is. One is that Chinese restaurant food is totally made up, and has no similarity with food anywhere in the world. In which case, I'd better give up trying to find the right location. This seems to be the case with [fried ice cream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fried_ice_cream), which Wikipedia suggests is an artificial modern invention.

The other is that maybe I visited the wrong location. China is a big place, after all. Perhaps visiting another area, such as Inner Mongolia, would find me what I'm looking for, with dishes either the same as, or the un-modified version of what is served in western countries' Chinese restaurants.

The Wikipedia article on [Chinese restaurant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_restaurant) mentions:

> There has additionally been a consequential component of Chinese
>   emigration of illegal origin, most notably Fuzhou people from Fujian
>   Province and Wenzhounese from Zhejiang Province in Mainland China,
>   specifically destined to work in Chinese restaurants in New York City,
>   beginning in the 1980s.

As Fujian province is right next to Taiwan, and has had a major influence on it, it seems plausible that if some of the "Chinese restaurant" dishes were coming from Fujian, I would have seen them in Taiwan, but I didn't.

Where, if anywhere, can I find the dishes that feature in western countries' Chinese restaurants? Also, how should I identify the right kind of eatery in those countries?

Comment: For European (read Dutch) "Chinese" restaurant, I am in understanding that a lot of it originates from Indonesia, but I do not have first hand experience on that, therefore not a full answer.

Comment: This problem also goes the other way round. Most western-style popular restaurants in Asia that I've tried don't taste like anything you'd get in Europe.

Comment: @Bernhard: That's fairly specific to the Netherlands (who were the former colonial power in Indonesia) but not elsewhere. And even in the Dutch case one has to account for the Chinese minority which lived in Indonesia. I suspect the British may have similar influences due to their former influence in South East Asia.

Comment: And European food in America and American food in Europe. And if you've actually been to Mexico you will find Mexican food in Australia very depressing indeed despite its new-found popularity.

Comment: Part of the experience of going to other countries is to experience foreign cuisine. So by looking for food that you are familiar and comfortable with, you are denying yourself an important part of the international travel experience. In addition, locals will think you are a typical American tourist thinking that you are still in America. (Why they don't teach basic things like this in our school system is beyond ridiculous.) American Chinese food is, in general, not actual Chinese food - as is the case with most types of cuisine in America. In general, you won't find Americanized Chinese food

Comment: The only place I've encountered fried ice cream is in a semi-authentic Mexican restaurant in the US. So I always thought it was fake Mexican food, not fake Chinese food.

Comment: It took me three long tours of Mexico before I found my first burrito for sale in a place not designed specifically for American customers. I had started to believe burritos were fake Mexican food!

Comment: @hippietrail Well, Cal-Mex (and Sonoran Cuisine, as well as Tex-Mex in general) is still Mexican food! It's just from a border region that has since been absorbed pretty wholly into the US.

Comment: Yes I think I finally found my first non-tourist burrito on a trip to Northern Mexico, where I hadn't spent much time. Only later did I find a non-tourist burrito place in Mexico City. My point is that what non Mexicans think of as representative of Mexican food is regional within Mexico rather than representative. And the same surely goes for all world cuisines when viewed from outside perspectives.

Comment: There are enough East Indians in the Toronto area that Indian-style Chinese food is reasonably well represented. Things like chili paneer. Often combined with Hakka cuisine. I can't imagine anyone outside Europe wanting German-style Chinese food, nor do I think Canadian-Chinese style sweet and sour chicken balls are in demand in China. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_balls

Comment: @drat: It should be mentioned, though, that especially in China, "Western style food" is sometimes understood also by Chinese as "Chinese food, eaten with knife and fork rather than chopsticks", or "Chinese food, ordered per person on a plate rather than in bowls in the middle of the table". In those cases, it is not *meant* to resemble any Western food in terms of ingredients or taste.

Comment: Don't be surprised to find out that quite a few traditional local specialties are "artificial modern inventions". Basically at least in Taiwan many people try their best to come up with a gimmick that will become a hit. Bubble tea is one that doesn't go back that many years. Night markets in Taiwan are full of both hits and misses in this category. It doesn't take that many years for a hit one to become a new local tradition. Some traditional Chinese dishes were invented in Chinatowns in Southeast Asia for instance.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Nowhere in China**.  [American Chinese cuisine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Chinese_cuisine#History) (and its relatives in Australia, Europe, etc) is heavily adapted for Western tastes:

> "Chinese-American cuisine is 'dumbed-down' Chinese food. It’s
>   adapted... to be blander, thicker and sweeter for the American public"

Some dishes are localized versions of actual Chinese dishes (eg. Kung Pao chicken, which completely lacks the *málà* kick of the Sichuanese original), many were created in America (fortune cookies, "Mongolian beef", etc).  The Wikipedia article above has a good list of both.

Also, I've eaten a lot of "real" Fujianese (Hokkien) food in Singapore, where they're the single largest dialect group, and I can assure you that neither [Fujian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fujian_cuisine) nor [Hakka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hakka_cuisine) cuisine bears the slightest resemblance to Panda Express.

Incidentally, this phenomenon is by no means unique.  For example, [Indian Chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Chinese_cuisine) is what happens when Chinese and Indian cuisines collide, in Japan you can try out heavily Japanized Western dishes (*[yōshoku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y%C5%8Dshoku)*) like "[omelette rice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omurice)", and *everybody* has bastardized the poor Italians.  Of course, things get really interesting when these get re-exported back to the home country, which is why you can now find [American Chinese food in Shanghai](http://www.npr.org/blogs/thesalt/2014/02/12/275628045/cornell-pair-introduce-american-chinese-food-to-shanghai)!

Comment: This must be like discovering Santa Claus isn't real. (Not that that happened to me - I don't recall ever believing he was real)

Comment: Similarly, I've read that there're a handful of restaurants in Japan selling the Americanized version of the local cuisine targeted toward nostalgic businessmen who spent a lot of time in the US in the '80's when authentic Japanese food was nearly impossible to find here.

Comment: Having grown up overseas (i.e. outside of the US, my native country), I never expect any local food anywhere to taste like it does in restaurants which supposedly serve its cuisine in other countries.

Comment: Why does the last sentence of your answer completely contradict the first sentence?

Comment: You even get this between provinces in China. Even westerners I met in China who had lived in Sichuan were complaining about how pale the approximations of Sichuan food were in the rest of China - even in neighbouring Yunnan!

Comment: Also, adapting to local tastes in only one of the factors. Another is the availability of ingredients. Substitute ingredients are widely used all over the world in cuisines of other cultures. Then there's economic incentive. Japanese restaurants run by Koreans or Vietnamese, Chinese restaurants which include versions of Thai dishes, Thai restaurants often have laksa, etc. There are preparation differences due to cultural differences. Indian dishes can take all day or longer to prepare the traditional way but most Indian restaurants are run is sensible western business hours.

Comment: There's also the incentive to sell the dishes the customers expect to find. Most Chinese restaurants in the west are based around versions of Hong Kong food. Most Indian restaurants in the west are based around versions of (I believe) Punjabi food. It's much tougher to sell dishes the customers are not familiar with unless you also have a large base of expat customers to feed.

Comment: +1 for "and *everybody* has bastardized the poor Italians", one of the most bastardized is probably spaghetti bolognese which is totally unheard of in Bologna because spaghetti isn't a traditional kind of pasta in Emilia.

Comment: I know it wasn't your quote, but I think it's judgmental to refer to one country's adaptation of another's food as "dumbed down." It's just different. That being said, having lived in Japan, I think people used to American Japanese restaurants, full of "rolls" made with things like avocado, would be quite surprised by the "plainness" of a sushi restaurant in Tokyo.

Comment: Judgmental? Yes. True? Yes.  Exported food is *always* "dumbed down", because that way it's less strange and sells better.  And it's slowly "smartened up" again as people get used to it and start looking for more authenticity.

Comment: @Geeo: Bah rubbish. Italian food has always been bastardized food from other places, and that's why it's so damn good (-: Just try to imagine Italian cuisine without the bastardized Chinese noodles and the bastardized American tomatoes!

Comment: @hippietrail I don't see how what you said contradict what I said. Also, we were talking about nowday dishes, the question is not about histoty of food.

Comment: @Geeo: It's all subjective in my opinion. American Italian food has been around for over a century for instance. Everybody can decide their personal cuttoff point between "history of food" and "nowaday dishes". There's no one of those opinions which is the "one right one".

Comment: @hippietrail Your point about the availability of ingredients is a good one. My favorite Pakistani restaurant in my area is very authentic but still tastes slightly different because of some substitutions. For example, they use jalapeno, which I had never eaten in any native Pakistani prepared dishes overseas.

Answer (score 7):

These foods are typically unique to where you eat them For example neither deep fried ice cream or honey chicken are ["Chinese food" here in Canada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_Chinese_cuisine). The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Chinese_cuisine) on American Chinese food does a pretty job of identifying which North American "Chinese food" dishes map to food you might eat in China and which do not. I don't know if you can construct a similar list for Australian "Chinese food", but look for ingredients like carrots and tomatoes, as well as anything salad-like, to be particular to your home version of Chinese food and less likely to be available in China or other parts of Asia.

Comment: I can assure you I ate plenty of tomatoes all over China. Especially in a soup with egg which made a very good and cheap breakfast. And I almost never ate in places for tourists in China. Don't forget that tomatoes like chilis and potatoes and corn originate from the Americas yet have become fully nativized ingredients in cuisines such as Chinese, Indian, Irish, Italian, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Fried ice cream (焼きアイスクリーム/"yaki aisukuriimu"), sweet-and-sour pork (酢豚/"subuta", lit. "vinegar pork") or chicken (酢鳥/"sudori") are well-known in Japan. If you find yourself in that part of the world, just ask the locals for these things by name.

> 酢鳥や酢豚など (sudori ya subuta nado) 食べたいんですから, (tabetain'desukara)
> この辺には (konohen ni wa) 中国式のレストラン (chuugoku-shiki no resutoran) 有りますか？(arimasuka?)
>
> (I would like to eat something like "sudori" or "subuta", is there a Chinese restaurant around here?)

If you want Chinese food in Japan, you go to a Chinese restaurant. Any larger mall has at least one. Sweet and sour chicken can also be found as prepared food in supermarkets and delis (like the food delis in the basements of larger malls).

For Mongolian food, it helps to find a Mongolian restaurant. In China, there is a good one in Shanghai called "Home in the Grasslands". In this restaurant, they actually have a few tables that are under Mongolian style tents (indoors). Lamb features prominently in the menu.

Lamb is is also used in some [Xi An](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xi%27an) style dishes ([Shaan-Xi cuisine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaanxi_cuisine)). If you see "Xi An" in the sign or the equivalent characters 西安, take a look.

Comment: Japanese Chinese has a bit of overlap with American Chinese (mostly in the neutered-and-spiceless sense), but most dishes are quite different: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_Chinese_cuisine And Am-Ch "Mongolian beef/lamb" has nothing to do with actual Mongol food, much less Xian's Shaanxi cuisine. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaanxi_cuisine

Comment: @jpatokal I gave the same Shannxi link in the answer; I only brought that up because of the connection with lamb meat, not because it is Mongolian in any sense.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the "Chinese" dishes you find let's say in Canada not being identical to the original, consider that China is a *huge* country. Chinese people living in one part of the country don't cook the same as Chinese people living in another part. The food that you find in Beijing might be very unusual to people in Taiwan. It's similar to asking for "European" food and not being able to find cannelloni in Athens (apart from the cannelloni you find in Italy not being quite what you expect).

Comment: Yes. I had to totally re-learn hot to order from non-tourist menus in Yunnan, then Northern China, then Taiwan. Few dishes were on the menu in any two of these areas, let alone all three.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a substantial answer, but I would like to point out that while some Westernised "Chinese" foods - such as Mongolian beef - do seem to be pretty nonexistent in Asia, others aren't.

For instance, I have seen many instances of sweet and sour pork (although the cooking style might be slightly different) in Hong Kong fast food restaurants, and I have definitely heard of fried ice cream (炸雪糕) while living in Asia.

In my experience though (which of course is somewhat idiosyncratic), these types of Chinese foods aren't really the type seen as epitome of Chinese cuisine, even if they're probably seen as more "Chinese" than eating pasta dishes or McDonald's.

Answer (score 2):

My wife is from Malaysia, and is ethnically Chinese (Hainanese).  When she first came to the US to visit, at some point we ended up buying some "Chinese" food at a local supermarket's deli area, probably something like Kung Pao chicken, but I don't exactly remember.  When we finally got it home to eat a short time later, she had no idea what she was looking at and asked me "what's this"?  When I explained what it was and she tasted it, she considered feeding it to our dogs instead.  I think she ate the rice and that was about it.

Fortunately there is a Chinese place in town where the owner makes a few "real" Chinese dishes that she just loves, so I can go have what I consider Chinese, and she can have "real" Chinese at the same restaurant.

When we travel to Malaysia & Singapore, we eat out a lot, but it's very-very-very rare to find what I think of as "Chinese" food, even though it's frequently Chinese food.  Fortunately I like most of that as well as the Malay and Indian foods everywhere.  However, after several weeks over there, I'm pining for some decent western food.  However...

If you're in Malaysia or Singapore and looking for something western-ish, try [Ramly-burger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramly_Burger) if you want a bit of east-west fusion in your burger, or [Nando's](http://www.nandos.com.my/nandos_my/) if you want some Portuguese style chicken thrown into the mix.  They're both fast food places I'd kill to have here in the Seattle area.

Comment: Nando's is not Malaysian/Singaporean but from South Africa. They have tended though to expand mostly only in Commonwealth countries and so far only a little in the US/Canada.

Comment: They may be from SA, but the peri-peri sauce they use on everything is very Portuguese in origin.