# Are there any restaurants serving real chinese food in Benelux?

Tags: food-and-drink, netherlands, belgium, asia, luxembourg

I read this question "[Where can I eat dishes that feature in western countries' Chinese restaurants?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30178/where-can-i-eat-dishes-that-feature-in-western-countries-chinese-restaurants)" and I got very curious. I always apreciated authentic Chinese food very much and I (sort of) knew that the dishes served in Ocident are, let's say, a striped down or adapted version, to serve better our tastes. I was not expecting it to be so radical though. (I am starting to wonder how sushi really tastes in Japan, or if they even have it like us).

Can I actually eat real asian food in a restaurant either in Benelux?
If yes, are there any guides or resources that will allow me to easily find them?

Comment: Your question might be too broad, and might be better focussed on some location.

Comment: This needs to be better focused on cuisine and location.  There are multiple places within New York alone that Chinese expats claim to serve authentic foods there are places that Thai expats serve authentic Thai food and there are places that Indian expats claim serve authentic Indian food, all varying by differences in cuisine by location of origin.  Not to mention large metropolitan areas like LA or San Francisco and this is just the US.

Comment: @Karlson, I understand your comment. Do you have any sugestions to improve the question? my initial idea was just to know if such restaurants existed and if they were available to a wider public. The question than grew into a "where" which makes it a bit broader. Any ideas to impreve the question are welcome. I can, of course, narrow the regional scope to Europe or less, but I think this might also be intersting to people in other locations.

Comment: @nsn They do exist and they are available to general public.  The thing is Asia = many countries each country may have different regions and thus different cuisines.  Secondly the authenticity of the cuisine isn't really an objective measure since I've had several expats from the same province in China nearly come to blows discussing authenticity of food in one restaurant in Queens.

Comment: @Karlson, again I agree, but than the only option is either narrow the question or delete it. In a way I tried to handle that asking for a resouce that list these places.

Comment: Just come to Toronto- you can get authentic cuisine from just about anywhere (LA might be a bit better for SE Asian such as Cambodian). I taste no difference between here and Seoul, Tokyo or Beijing for similar items.

Comment: @nsn Yelp, Zagat just off the top of my head but again authenticity judgement is highly subjective plus you need to narrow down the cuisine and the region.  North America is a big place with lots of expats from various Asian descents, same goes for Europe.

Answer (score 6):

Of course there are specialized restaurants that offer the "real" Chinese food. I don't think there is a general method to find them, other than asking Chinese people that were not born in the country. They will know these places in the city they are living. Except for restaurants, there are also dedicated supermarkets that sell items that you won't find in your own supermarket.

In my city Rotterdam, Netherlands, I went to such a [restaurant](http://www.sansan33.nl/) with a Chinese colleague. The food was a lot alike the food I had in restaurants in China.

Answer (score 4):

The streets around [Van Wesenbeekstraat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Wesenbekestraat) in Antwerp, Belgium, are known as the local "Chinatown". You will find a lot of restaurants there that are operated and frequently visited by the local Chinese community. My sister used to live in China for a few years and confirmed me that you can find "real" Chinese food there.
There are also some restaurants in the same neighborhood with other authentic Asian cuisines.

Answer (score 3):

Antwerp has a few.
They have a few "Sichuan" restaurants。
I tried "Dragon City", which is quite authentic, and not so expensive.
Add: Langeleemstraat 88,2018 Antwerpen

Answer (score 2):

In Amsterdam you will find such restaurants in Zeedijk, the end of the street nearest Nieuwmarkt, as well as in some of the streets around it. Indeed the bit of Amsterdam that is 'almost' China town.